# Loading chunk 'XY' failed on client PC running Ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 and lazy loading. App is running perfectly fine on 12 PCs. In one PC, it has started saying "Loading chunk 7 failed" , sometimes the no. is 43,37

What I have tried:

1. Deleted node_modules and re installed
2. build the web app using this command: npm run build --aot --output-hashing none
3. cleared browser cache
4. Tried this fix - https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/530

My `ionic info` of app

```
  ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.2 (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
ionic)
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.3
  @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

System:

  NodeJS : v10.8.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
  npm    : 6.2.0
  OS     : Windows Server 2008
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Pro-tips for posting: (1) please only use quote blocks as a quote device i.e. to highlight that some material is not in your own voice; (2) when using an ordered list, make sure it is formatted correctly in Markdown so it is recognised. (3) refrain from adding please-help begging, and how much you will appreciate answers, and other conversational material not germane to the problem. Generally, technical writing is preferred here.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve issues with the client caching lazy loaded modules by setting the `preloadingStrategy`. However, I was having this issue even with `--output-hashing all`, but I would still suggest you try that first.

---

To enable a `preloadingStrategy` add the following into your `RouterModule`.

```
import {PreloadAllModules, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
})
```

---

This approach gets the lazy modules in the background with the added benefit of updating the chunk hash and (from what I've seen) forcing the browser cache to update.

Comment: Problem doesnt seem to be on ionic side, because diagnosis shows 1. when i copied the same build in local xampp it worked 2. When i copied the same build on another server it worked from there aswell , Please note - It is only 1 PC which gives this error from one url, again saying if i run same build from another server url it works. What can be the issue ?